# How do you delete a Visual Studio Marketplace publisher?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

How do you delete a Visual Studio Marketplace publisher?

Looking around my account on https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/manage/publishers/
I can't see anything in the UI for "delete publisher", only the "create publisher" option

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is currently no way in the UI to delete a publisher ... *at least, as of 2019-01-15*

You can delete using the `tfx cli` ...

```
tfx extension publisher delete --publisher mypublisherid
```

Comment: I guess the command is moved from tfx to vsce

Answer (score 13):

Steve must first remove the publisher from the list. To check if it is in the list, run in console:

```
vsce ls-publishers
```

Then if you see the publisher in the list execute the following:

```
vsce logout <name-publisher>
```

And finally to eliminate the publisher:

```
vsce delete-publisher <name-publisher>
```

PD You will probably need the token you used to create it.

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/publishing-extension

Comment: Thanks for answer, however vsce is the cli for visual studio code extensions. I needed to use the tfx cli

Comment: Oops!! mistake, I was looking at the stackoverflow posts for a solution for the same thing, but in VSCE, and in the end I discovered how to fix it, so I wanted to share my solution with you.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear if you're trying to delete the publisher or whether you're trying to delete the offering for a publisher. It sounds like the former--the answer probably is the same, either way...

To remove an offering: The publisher agreement (https://cdn.vsassets.io/v/M143_20181113.44/_content/Visual-Studio-Marketplace-Publisher-Agreement.pdf) states on page 7 (Section 7(a)) that you may remove an offering with 30 days' notice (be sure to read the Removal policy in Exhibit A).

To do that, contact support at this email:
vsmarketplace@microsoft.com

To remove a publisher, I the same email above would very likely be able to help. If you find that there's a better way, please update us here.

Comment: I'm trying to delete the actual publisher. Contacted vsmarketplace but no response as yet