# How do I remove a Visual Studio Marketplace publisher under my account?

Tags: azure-devops-extensions

I am not able to delete publishers from the UI and there is no option for deleting via the [tfx-cli](https://github.com/microsoft/tfs-cli) either.

No options in the UI in marketplace and tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54197823/14404513) but there is no such command in the cli.

Comment: I'm guessing [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-vsce) with the command `vsce delete-publisher <publisher>` should do it.

Comment: See my answer, there are detailed steps. It works fine on my side. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-vsce/blob/2589114ed647fc63f0501be95f9dcdff794ddffa/src/main.ts#L262).

For example, you need a user that have permission like 'Owner' in marketplace 'publisher' instance.

You need to generate a Personal Access Token on DevOps side that have these permission:

[image]

Or you can simply select the 'Full access' section of the 'Scopes'.

After that, install the tool 'vsce':

`npm install --global vsce`

After the tool installed successfully, run this command:

`vsce delete-publisher <publisher ID>`

After give the personal access token and confirmation, the publisher will delete successfully:

[image]

**Notice:**

The publisher ID is here:

[image]

Comment: This solution works but I can't delete the publisher because:
You can't remove extension '<extension_name>' because it's installed on at least one organization.
This is annoying because I uninstalled that extension from my organisation but since I published it publicly it won't let me delete that extension from my publisher.